# Local notification in ios objective c based on traffic(travel time) and date time

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, date, uilocalnotification

In my project i want to implement local notifications based on Date Time and traffic between two locations. I have some tasks in server, whenever I get data I want to save locally and tasks will have task time and Location.

So based on Date & time and the current location and location to go (Based on traffic we can get travel time from google API's I feel). How can we handle this scenario.

Comment: if your app has background running functionality then you can fetch the location while travelling. Just comparing the location or broadly say regions from your stored record you can display an alert to user.

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html

Section:
Deferring Location Updates While Your App Is in the Background

Activating location background task, based on location, the app will receive events on the move, without requiring activate an timed background task.

You have an example at this link:

https://www.raywenderlich.com/143128/background-modes-tutorial-getting-started